# D3 - force layout, circle within circle

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

In the process of learning D3.js.

Is it possible using a force layout to place a circle within another circle shape as per the picture. I am hoping to transition between a single circle per node to a display showing two circles per node. The size of the effective donut is used to illustrate another variable in the data.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is possible. The force layout is agnostic to what is being drawn, so you can have groups of objects instead of single ones.

Comment: Thanks Lars. Do you have an example? Are you saying I can create multiple shapes per node? Sorry, I am only just getting used to D3.

Comment: I didn't find an example, but yes, that's basically it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to use anything other than a basic svg circle, as you find in most examples.  Just bind the data to it, apply a stroke, and set the stroke-width attr to your other variable.  Or `r - otherVar`, I'm sure you can figure that part out.

If this doesn't satisfy, build your own shape.  The ['g' svg element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#Groups) is a container element, and lets you build whatever you like.  Add two circles to a g, fill them how you like.  Make sure to add them in the right order, since svg has no concept of 'on top', things just get painted in the order that you add them.

edit: okay, quick demo so you can learn some syntax.  I didn't add any comments but hopefully the code is very verbose and straightforward.  [Find it here.](http://bl.ocks.org/roippi/6044065)

d3/svg is something that you have to just bash your head against for a while.  I highly recommend spending some time creating a sandbox environment where you can quickly test new things, save, refresh browser to see results.  Minimizing that turnaround time is key.

Comment: This is an interesting idea but I would like to achieve the desired outcome without altering the stroke. I already apply a stroke to the circle which aids in the shapes comprehension on screen.

Comment: Well, that's fine, if you want to build your own shape you can do that.  As Lars says, the force layout doesn't care what you make the nodes look like.  I'll edit a bit more info in.

Comment: What I can't seem to find is the syntax how to create a group which consists of two circle shapes. Creating a group for SVG shapes of differing type is OK, but how do you group two circles together?

Comment: Okay, one more edit.  Made a quick demo to help on syntax.  This is more of a "how do I svg" question than "how do I d3" question, but that's fine, this stuff is not particularly intuitive.  I recommend at the very minimum going through this entire tutorial: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/

Comment: Thanks for your help roippi. Your information pointed me in the right direction. I have a desktop based IDE which I use to work in D3, Raphael, Processing.js, Paper and Dygraphs. I'll post another answer with a screenshot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to roippi I was able to create a group containing two circle shapes.

```
var nodeCircles = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(nodes);

    // Outer circle 
var outer = nodeCircles
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node_circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius_plus; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color_plus; })    
    .style("opacity", 0);   

    // Inner circle
var inner = nodeCircles
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node_circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })        
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })    
    .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
    .on("mouseout", mouseOut)
    .call(force.drag);
```

Outer circle visibility is toggled via a button.

[image]

As mentioned, I use a desktop based IDE to run/test visualisation languages. Currently the IDE supports studies written in D3.js, Raphael, Processin.js, Paper.js and Dygraphs. Picture below...

[image]

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for posting your solution, that is always helpful for people who stumble upon the thread via googling.